# I am doing a training project and have encountered a problem

Tags: django, for-loop, url, view, model

I am doing a training project and have encountered a problem. I try to display the "events" block and the "news" block on the main page, but when I run the loop cycle, only one block is displayed, and the second is not displayed. Explain who knows what I'm doing wrong. I have been solving this problem for three days now. Thanks in advance who will respond to help

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

{% if post %}
    {% for post in post %}
        {{ post.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>У вас нет материала</p>
{% endif %}
{% if event %}
    {% for event in event %}
        {{ event.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>У вас нет материала</p>
{% endif %}



</body>
</html>
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.views.generic.base import View

from .models import Blog, Event
# Create your views here.

class EventView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        event = Event.objects.all()
        return render(request, "home/home_list.html", {"event": event})

class BlogView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        post = Blog.objects.all()
        return render(request, "home/home_list.html", {"post": post})
```

Urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.EventView.as_view()),
    path("", views.BlogView.as_view())
```

]

Models:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date

# Create your models here.

class Blog(models.Model):
    """Новости"""
    title = models.CharField("Заголовок", max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField("Описание")
    descriptionTwo = models.TextField("Описание (второй абзац)", blank=True, default="")
    blockquote = models.TextField("Цитата", blank=True, default="")
    short = models.TextField("Краткое описание", max_length=300)
    poster = models.ImageField("Изображение", upload_to="post/")
    prewiew = models.ImageField("Превью", upload_to="post/")
    dataPost = models.DateField("Дата публикации", default=date.today)
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True, blank=True)
    draft = models.BooleanField("Черновик", default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Новости"
        verbose_name_plural = "Новости"


class Event(models.Model):
    """События"""
    name = models.CharField("Заголовок", max_length=100)
    adress = models.TextField("Адрес")
    description = models.TextField("Описание")
    short = models.TextField("Краткое описание")
    phone = models.TextField("Контактный номер телефона")
    email = models.EmailField()
    image = models.ImageField("Изображение", upload_to="event/")
    dataStart = models.DateField("Дата старта", default=date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Событие"
        verbose_name_plural = "События"
```

Admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Blog, Event

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Event)
admin.site.register(Blog)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Views

You need one view with a context containing both the `events` ant the `posts`

```
class EventView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        events = Event.objects.all()
        posts = Blog.objects.all()
        return render(request, "home/home_list.html", {"events": events, "posts":posts})
```

## Template

In the template loop over both

```
{% if posts %}
{% for p in posts %}
    {{ p.title }}
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<p>У вас нет материала</p>
{% endif %}
{% if events %}
{% for e in events %}
        {{ e.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>У вас нет материала</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

In for each loop, use different name for the "loop Object" and the list/dictionary on which you are looping. LIKE THIS:

```
{% if post %}
    {% for p in post %}
        {{ p.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>У вас нет материала</p>
{% endif %}
{% if event %}
    {% for e in event %}
        {{ e.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>У вас нет материала</p>
{% endif %}
```

Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks your answer helped in part, but it was supplemented by bb4L editing the context